# ASP.MVC change _Layout elements from controller or view level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have shared _Layout that has partial menu and body (RenderBody). I would like to control on controller or view level how _Layout is rendered. For one controller action or view i would like to hide menu (part of _Layout), for other i would like to show it.

Is there any explicit solution to do that? Something like:

thisView.Layout.HideMenu = true

Comment: Create one more layout without menu and use it

Comment: Those 2 layouts would share same logic, its additional maintenance when it comes to updating this logic. In solution i'm working with Layout is quite complicated.

Comment: 2 layouts would be best, but you can always pass a value in a base view model or `ViewBag` to indicate if the elements should be displayed - `@if (ViewBag.IncludeMenu) { // render menu }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a base ViewModel with a boolean property `bool showMenu {get; set;}` then make your other ViewModels inherit from the base ViewModel.

Finally, in your `_Layout.cshtml` (which will take the base ViewModel as its `@model`) you can do a Razor `if(Model.showMenu)`. When true, your menu will render, when false, it'll be hidden.

Comment: Sounds interesting but should i care about passing this attributes over forms? I mean when posting data model will be binded to form - isn't it?

Comment: It is up to you, if you want the form content to determine how the flag is set, then yes you can control the flag however you want. If the form is unrelated, then you don't need to pass it in the form

Comment: You could also store this value in a [ViewBag](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/1286/viewdata-viewbag-tempdata/4231/what-are-viewdata-viewbag-and-tempdata) property, instead of adding it to the ViewModel.

Comment: You can indeed.I find ViewModels easier to debug, but yes, you could use a ViewBag too.

Comment: Ok, that's one of possible solutions, I'll mark it as possible answer. I have implemented another solution with class describing layout properties. Instance of this class is stored inside singleton and lives with request. It is available on each level of project: layout, controller action and view. Thanks for help.